# How to hide drop-down menu in Bootstrap 3.3.4 dynamically using jQuery in document-ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

I've following Bootstrap HTML code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="projects" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle projects" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="projects">Projects</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/projectList.html">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/createNewProject.html">Add new project</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Now I want to hide the drop-down menu using jQuery code i.e. I want to hide the drop-down menus **List and Add new project**.

I want this to be done in document-ready function. You can add the specific ids to the suitable tag to make the thing work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why jQuery? why not by simple CSS?

Comment: Like this `$('.dropdown-menu', '.projects').hide()`?

Comment: @Malik:I want to do it using jQuery only as I'm applying some condition for showing and hiding the menu in jQuery code.

Comment: @Malik:Can you please provide css code for the same?

Comment: `ul.dropdown-menu > li { display: none;  }`

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown-menu").children().hide();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I have removed my comment because it was incorrect

Comment: It hides the drop-down but a small white color background still appears under the main menu 'Projects'. How to remove that?

Comment: i'm not seeing this background when using the nav code you provided in a jsfiddle. can you provide me with your exact code so I can take a look?

Comment: Can you please give me your jsfiddle link?

Comment: @user2839497 here is a link to mine http://jsbin.com/kuvogitosi/edit?html,js,output